# Core Data does returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO also fault relationships upon fetch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

I am faulting all properties of my managed object upon fetch to gain a performance benefit as I will use them all and the result set is small. However, are relationships also faulted during the fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFetchRequest) it only mentions properties being pre-fetched, not relationships. I bet relationships remain faulted.

---

However, you can easily find out yourself - just look at the object in the log :)

For example, if you have Company has many Employees and you ask for a company, when you debug this (assuming you haven't overridden the description method)

```
NSLog(@"%@", company);
```

you will get something *like*

```
<Company 0x123456
  name : "Company Name"
  employees : <NSSet data:fault>
>
```

If it wasn't faulted, you would see a list of Employees instead of the word *fault* :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is pretty old, but it looks like Apple has added an option to set which relationships should be prefetched rather than faulted:

Here's a snippet taken from NSFetchRequest.h

```
/* Returns/sets an array of relationship keypaths to prefetch along with the entity for the request.  The array contains keypath strings in NSKeyValueCoding notation, as you would normally use with valueForKeyPath.  (Prefetching allows Core Data to obtain developer-specified related objects in a single fetch (per entity), rather than incurring subsequent access to the store for each individual record as their faults are tripped.)  Defaults to an empty array (no prefetching.) 
*/
- (NSArray *)relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching NS_AVAILABLE(10_5,3_0);
- (void)setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:(NSArray *)keys NS_AVAILABLE(10_5,3_0);
```